# Set size of image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I use Photoshop and now starting on Illustrator but I can't work out how to change the size of the overall image.  I have opened a pre-existing one but unlike Photoshop I can't see where to find the existing size then to be able to enter the new required size.  Example is the current file is 64cm wide and I want to go to 100cm and keep the proportions constrained

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are you trying to make the artboard bigger, or just the graphics in it? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

**There are many possible ways**

but as you already uses photoshop I'm gonna tell you little similar.

=> If you want to change size of artboard(canvas in photoshop) you can do it either via  artboard tool ( shortcut is <kbd>Shift+O</kbd> ) or either by going to `Document setup - Edit artboard - Desired size`

=> now if you want to scale image the best practice is to do same as photoshop while turning smart guides on. ( select layer and dragging transformation circle while pressing Shift to keep proportions constrained )  and if you want to scale it by absolute width like in percent then go to `Object - Transform - Scale` and if you want to scale to exact value then just use the tool bar and edit the value ( below is the image )

==> image contains practice of scaling artboard via bar and scaling via both dragging and bar . sorry couldn't add other methods because of size limit of gif.

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you Design Phoenix, exactly what I was looking for - Saved me :)

Comment: glad it helped you! don't forget to mark answer as accepted if it resolved your problem :)